# How to pivot a dataframe with pandas to display values with aggregation and without aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pivot my dataframe using pandas, my dataframe look like this

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD0yg.png)

I want `shop_id` with maximum `item_cnt_day` with maximum sold `item_id` sorted by `date_block_num` in descending order.

I have tried this

```
pd.pivot_table(sales1,index=['date_block_num', 'shop_id'], values=["item_cnt_day","item_id"], \
               aggfunc={"item_id":lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax(),'item_cnt_day':sum}).\
            sort_values(by=['date_block_num','item_cnt_day'], ascending=False).reset_index().head(10)
```

[Result dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dhwt.png) (Not allowed to embed images as per stackoverflow)

i want only one row per `date_block` with `shop_id` having maximum `item_cnt_day` with `item_id` sold maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two aggregation steps like:

```
# first group by all three attributes to get one line per
# this three columns
grouped=df.groupby(['date_block_no', 'shop_id', 'item_id'])

# and just aggregate the item_cnt_day you want to have listed
aggregated=grouped.aggregate({'item_cnt_day': 'sum'})

# make the index columns regular columns again and resort
# so the highest sales come first (btw. I think you could remove
# date_block_no form the sort if you like, but it doesn't hurt)
aggregated.reset_index(inplace=True)
aggregated.sort_values(['date_block_no', 'item_cnt_day'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

# now aggregate the intermediate result again, but this time
# only by date_block_no and only keep the first row per
# group, which is the one with the highest sales, because we
# sorted it this way above
aggregated.groupby(['date_block_no']).aggregate('first')
```